# Is it possible to use linux/rbtree.h (Linux kernel's rbtree implementation) for my program ? Or should it be used only for writing kernel modules?

Tags: c, linux, red-black-tree

I require red black trees for some program of mine. I read around and saw that linux kernel has a rbtree implementation available. I just downloaded the header files using my linux's package manager and included the linux/rbtree.h and wrote sample code as per the linux/Documentation/rbtree.txt.

However, I am getting compilation errors when i try to use the same. Please see below my compilation steps.

```
[shankar@shankar-pc]$ gcc id_mgmt_library.c -I/lib/modules/4.14.155-1-MANJARO/build/include/
In file included from /lib/modules/4.14.155-1-MANJARO/build/include/linux/kernel.h:7,
                 from /lib/modules/4.14.155-1-MANJARO/build/include/linux/rbtree.h:32,
                 from id_mgmt_library.c:4:
/lib/modules/4.14.155-1-MANJARO/build/include/linux/linkage.h:8:10: fatal error: asm/linkage.h: No such file or directory
    8 | #include <asm/linkage.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

Comment: You should probably use the copies from `/usr/include` if you want to use them in your program. However, it would probably be a better idea to implement your own.